# jhipster with oauth2/OIDC option : csrf disabled in generated java config but called in angular UI

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jhipster, openid-connect

I'm using Jhipster 4.13.3 with the Oauth2/OIDC option to generate a gateway connected keycloak.
I think there could be an inconsistency in the generated code, or I missed something ;)

In the java config (MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration.java and oAuth2Ss0Configuration.java), CSRF is disabled.

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

But in the Angular UI (auth-session.service.ts), a resource is called to refresh the CSRF token.

```
logout(): Observable<any> {
        // logout from the server
        return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/logout', {}).map((response: Response) => {
            // to get a new csrf token call the api
            this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/account')
```

So, first question, is that call to refresh CSRF token really needed since the CSRF protection is disabled ?

Second question, why is CSRF disabled ? I don't see access_token on the client, it's probably on the server, but there's a jsessionid cookie stored on the client, could it be stolen and used by csrf attack ?

Thanks !

Philippe

Comment: If you remove the call to refresh the CSRF token, does everything still work? If so, feel free to submit a patch!

Comment: Thanks Matt. It seems to be ok without the call. But as I'm a newbie with OAuth2, I don't understand why CSRF is disabled in this case. Could somebody give me a link or a simple explanation ?

Comment: I wasn't awake, cors is disabled on the jhipster gateway and Authorisation code flow is used by my keycloak config. So, no csrf needed.